# How can I finish this JavaScript RockPaperScissors made with radiobuttons and a function? (Not homework)

Tags: javascript, html, function, logic

I'm honestly curious because I'm able to make the RockPaperScissors game in javascript through prompts and numbers... but I now wanted to know how to do it with radiobuttons and using a function. Here's what I have so far but not sure where to begin with the logic.

**JavaScript**

```
function RPSGame()
{
comp = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);
if (RPS.radiobutton[0].checked == true) && (comp === RPS.radiobutton[0])
    document.RPS.result.value = ("A Tie!");


}
```

I assume I'll be using an IF ELSE nested loop like I have in just javascript prompts, but I'm not so adept in functions.

**HTML**

```
<form name = "RPS">
<p>Rock Paper Scissors <br>
<input type = "radio" name="radiobutton" value ="1"/>Rock <br>
<input type = "radio" name="radiobutton" value ="2"/>Paper <br>
<input type = "radio" name="radiobutton" value ="3"/>Scissors <br>

<br>
<input type = "button" name="Play" value="Play" onclick="RPSGame(RPS)"/><br> <br>
<input type="button" onclick="clearDoc();" value="Clear" />
<input type = "text" name ="result" size = "8">
</p>
</form>
```

Again this is not homework, I understand this is probably more of a tutorial-esque question. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

**JavaScript**

```
function RPSGame()
{
comp = Math.floor(Math.random()*3+1);


 if ((comp == 1) && (RPS.radiobutton[2].checked))
 { document.RPS.result.value = ("You LOSE!"); }
  else if ((comp == 1) && (RPS.radiobutton[1].checked))
  { document.RPS.result.value = ("You won!"); }
   else if ((comp == 1) && (RPS.radiobutton[0].checked))
    {document.RPS.result.value = ("Tie!"); }

   else if ((comp == 2) && (RPS.radiobutton[0].checked))
   { document.RPS.result.value = ("You LOSE!"); }
    else if ((comp == 2) && (RPS.radiobutton[1].checked))
    { document.RPS.result.value = ("TIE!"); }
     else if ((comp == 2) && (RPS.radiobutton[2].checked))
     { document.RPS.result.value = ("You won!"); }

     else if ((comp == 3) && (RPS.radiobutton[0].checked))
      { document.RPS.result.value = ("You won!"); }
       else if ((comp == 3) && (RPS.radiobutton[1].checked))
        { document.RPS.result.value = ("You LOSE!"); }
         else if ((comp == 3) && (RPS.radiobutton[2].checked))
          { document.RPS.result.value = ("TIE!"); }
           else 
            { document.RPS.result.value = ("Nothing!"); }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name = "RPS">
<p>Rock Paper Scissors <br>
<input type = "radio" name="radiobutton" value ="1"/>Rock <br>
<input type = "radio" name="radiobutton" value ="2"/>Paper <br>
<input type = "radio" name="radiobutton" value ="3"/>Scissors <br>

<br>
<input type = "button" name="Play" value="Play" onclick="RPSGame(RPS)"/><br> <br>
<input type="button" onclick="clearDoc(RPSGame);" value="Clear" />
<input type = "text" name ="result" size = "8">
</p>
</form>
```